# Region refresh, jQuery

Tags: oracle-apex

I have classic report with data about uploaded images. In same page I uploading photos and updating  classic report. Problem is that when I refreshing classic report jQuery Selector (Dynamic Action) doesn't work. Table in classic report have column `REMOVE_LINK` with value `NULL`. That column have link, target is: `javascript:void(0);`, and attributes: `data-id="#ID#" class="remove t-Icon fa fa-trash delete-irrow"`. Dynamic Action selection type is `jQuery Selector` and selector is `#REPORT_PHOTOS .remove`. I tried to refresh this region with JavasSript Code `$('#REPORT_PHOTOS').trigger('apexrefresh');` and Refresh action. Result is same - after classic report refresh, links doesn't works. Where is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Dynamic Action's **Event Scope** to **Dynamic**.

> **Event Scope**
>
> Select the scope of the event, which determines when the event is evaluated a second or successive time.
>
> Available options include:
>
> **Static** (default)
>
> Binds the event handler to the triggering element(s) for the lifetime of the current page, but is no longer bound if a triggering element is updated via Partial Page Refresh (PPR).
>
> **Dynamic**
>
> Binds the event handler to the triggering element(s) for the lifetime of the current page, irrespective of any triggering elements being recreated via Partial Page Refresh (PPR).
>
> **Once**
>
> Binds the event handler to the triggering element(s) only once. The dynamic action is not triggered again until after the page has been fully refeshed.